Is there an better/efficient way to keep asking for user input from STDIN using fgets() in C?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSIZE 10

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char input[MAXSIZE], c, *input_ptr;
    input_tag: printf("Enter the initial data string : ");
    input_ptr = fgets(input, MAXSIZE, stdin);                    //get input
    if(input_ptr != NULL && strcspn(input,"\n") == MAXSIZE-1){   //check if input fits in buffer
        printf("Buffer overflow. Reduce size of input.\n");
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n')                           //loop through rest of STDIN to discard extra characters until newline
        goto input_tag;                                          //Request for user input again
    }
    input[strcspn(input,"\n")] = '\0';                           //Remove newline character
    printf("Input is %s\n", input);
    return 0;
}

Is it possible to keep requesting the user for new input without using the goto statement?
Is there a better way to do what I have done? Because, I keep reading that using goto statement should be avoided if possible.

Define "better". Define "efficient". Which do you prefer? "better" of "efficient"?

goto has legitimate uses in C.  Looping is not one of them (though breaking out of a deep loop nest sometimes is).  Use C's built-in looping constructs to loop -- for, while, do ... while.  Avoid goto altogether until you understand well how to do without.  Then you'll be able to make an informed decision about what you might or might not gain by using goto in any given situation.

Do not modify the question so as to invalidate answers.  I've rolled back your change that did that.

For an example of how to prompt a user for a string (using printf/fgets), have a look at getstr in my answer: Check if all values entered into char array are numerical It also has a getnum

I feel bad for the user who is chided for trying to input too much data, but not told what the limit is.

A do/while loop can be used to avoid goto.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSIZE 10

int main ( void){
    char input[MAXSIZE] = "";
    int c = 0;
    size_t count = 0;

    do {
        printf("Enter the initial data string : ");
        if ( NULL == fgets(input, MAXSIZE, stdin)) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem fgets returned NULL\n");
            return 1;
        }
        count = strcspn ( input, "\n"); // count to newline or terminating zero
        // printf ( "count %zu\n", count);
        if ( input[count] != '\n') { // did not count to newline
            while ( ( c = getchar ( )) != '\n') {
                if ( EOF == c) {
                    if ( 0 != count) {
                        break;
                    }
                    fprintf ( stderr, "found EOF\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            if ( EOF != c) {
                printf ( "\nBuffer overflow. Reduce size of input.\n");
            }
        }
    } while ( input[count] != '\n' && EOF != c);

    input[count] = '\0'; //Remove newline character
    printf ( "Input is %s\n", input);
    return 0;
}


Error on my part concerning infinite loop.  Yes the if ( EOF == c) { prevents that.


Is there a better way to do what I have done?

Yes.
Code has at least these problems:
No loop
while((c = getchar()) != '\n') goto input_tag; does not loop.
Maybe OP wanted while((c = getchar()) != '\n'); goto input_tag;.
IAC, a goto is not needed.  Another while() loop is a better alternative.
Potential UB
input[strcspn(input,"\n")] = '\0'; is attempted when the prior fgets(input, ...) returns NULL.  input[] might not contain string.
Likewise for printf("Input is %s\n", input);.
Infinite loop
char c; ... while((c = getchar()) != '\n') is an infinite loop when getchar() returns EOF due to an end-of-file.
c should be an int.
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && C != EOF) is more common and not so error prone.
Wrong check in a corner case
strcspn(input,"\n") == MAXSIZE-1 is not certainly wrong when the next character read is an end-of-file indication.

I do not see a great alternative solution using fgets() to read a line.
Things to consider (some are pedantic):

Form a helper function.

How to indicate that the line is too long.

How to cope when null characters are read?  How to inform caller of # of characters read?

Proper handling of an input error vs. end-of-file.

Distinguishing reading some text and then encountering end-of-fife vs. a line.

Reading into a buffer longer than INT_MAX - uber pedantic.



IMHO, C lacks a great read_a_line() function.
I'd want something like:
int read_a_line(FILE *stream, size_t dsize, char dest[dsize], size_t *length_read) returning 1 on unqualified success, EOF on nothing read/input error and 0 otherwise.
Good luck.

If you're allowed to use posix functions, getline() is handy.

@Shawn True about getline(), yet that gets into allocation, memory management and does not prevent a user from overwhelming resources.  Here I am particular answering about non-allocating approaches like OP.

A sample alternative.
It is not that great considering the restrictive assert() and trouble when reading null characters.
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*
 * Read a line - primarily via fgets() using prompts.
 *
 * Save up to size-1 characters and form a string.  Do not save a '\n'.
 *
 * Return NULL on nothing more read or input error.
 * Re-read if input is too long.
 * Otherwise return buffer.
 */
char* read_a_line(size_t size, char *buffer, const char *prompt,
    const char *reprompt) {
  // Test parameters.
  // Some reasonable functionality is still possible with parameters that do not meet the assert.
  // Yet for simplicity of this demo code, they are enforced via an assert().
  assert(size > 1 && size <= INT_MAX && buffer);

  size_t length;
  for (;;) {
    if (prompt) {
      fputs(prompt, stdout);
    }
    // Get the line.
    if (fgets(buffer, (int) size, stdin) == NULL) {
      return NULL;
    }

    length = strlen(buffer);
    // Was less then the entire buffer used?
    // Note that reading a null character fools this code.
    // Hence a weakness of using `fgets()`.
    if (length + 1 < size) {
      break;
    }
    // Was the last character read a '\n'?
    if (buffer[length] == '\n') {
      break;
    }

    // If the _next_ character read is the end of the line,
    // then that is OK.
    int ch = fgetc(stdin);
    if (ch == '\n') {
      break;
    }
    if (ch == EOF) {
      return feof(stdin) ? buffer : NULL /* Input error */;
    }

    // Line is too long.  Now read rest of it.
    // Here we could use `fgets()` again,
    // yet the various cases complicate code, so go for simplicity.
    do {
      ch = fgetc(stdin);
      if (ch == EOF) {
        return NULL;
      }
    } while (ch != '\n');

    prompt = reprompt;
  }

  // Lop off a potential '\n'.
  if (length > 0 && buffer[length - 1] == '\n') {
    buffer[--length] = '\0';
  }
  return buffer;
}


I think I prefer the idea of this function only doing one read and indicating failure or success, as suggested in your original answer. Then re-reading or not is left to a caller.

@Chris I agree, yet rather than only 2: failure or success, I see a 3rd: EOF-like result to indicate no need to re-try.  Still, I wanted to give OP an alternative that somewhat followed their code's goal.  IAC, C lacks a good way to cleanly read a line into a fixed size buffer as a string.

Correction: C's standard library lacks good ways to do a lot of things. :)

@Chris Everybody complains about the C, but nobody does anything about it

Sure they do, and then we either tell them not to use it because it's not part of the standard, or they just start mispronouncing "C" as "rust" or "go."
